# setOnClickLister keeps crashing for new Activty

Tags: android, kotlin

On one page, I have a memory game level and I created a menu so once a button has been pressed it will take you to that page. The problem is each time I press the button my app crashes.

```
class Main2Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

        buttonEasy.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Plz share your layout code too.

Comment: look at the crash log. main cause is NullPointerException. Usually occurs if you have multiple layouts for different orientation, or you use the id of a view from a different layout.

Comment: Is your **Button** `buttonEasy` belongs to `R.layout.activity_main2`?

Comment: It seems to be missing the reference to the button.

Use data binding or findViewById.

Can you give us the error?

Answer (score 1):

First You Need To Intialized Your Button (buttonEasy)

```
buttonEasy = findViewById(R.id.buttonEasy);
```

Write OnClick Method For Both Types :

```
buttonEasy.setOnClickListener(object: View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(view: View): Unit {
        val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
})
```

Or you can write as

```
buttonEasy.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent);
   }
```

After then you getting still errors & crashing your app, check your MainActivity Code and verify your xml file.

Comment: It is **kotlin** and he use **kotlin synthetic properties**. So no need to use **findViewById**

Comment: you dont need to initialize view in kotlin